# Show that $\sup\left\{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\{|f|<\varepsilon\}}|f'(x)|dx:\varepsilon\in(0,1]\right\}$ is finite

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed and bounded interval and let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function $f\in C^1([a,b])$. I am trying to bound from above the following expression $$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\{|f|<\varepsilon\}}|f'(x)|dx$$ uniformly as $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$.

I would like to prove $$\sup\left\{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\{|f|<\varepsilon\}}|f'(x)|dx:\varepsilon\in(0,1]\right\}$$ is finite but I have no idea of how to do it. Any suggestions?

---

Olivier made me realise I should probably explain how this came up, so I will explain the original question. Consider the step function approximation of Dirac's delta $\delta^\varepsilon(t)=\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\textbf{1}_{\{|t|<\varepsilon\}}$. I would like to justify for $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ the equation $$\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0}\int_0^T\delta^\varepsilon(f(t))|f'(t)|dt=\int_0^T\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\delta^\varepsilon(f(t))|f'(t)|dt$$

Any hints on this would be equally helpful.

Comment: $\{|f|<\varepsilon\}=\{x\in [a,b]: |f(x)|<\varepsilon\}$

Comment: From where is the problem / how did it come up?

Comment: The equation which you want to prove (i.e. the one in the second part of your question) does not hold true; just consider $f(x) := x$.

Comment: @AdrianoMeis Don't forget to accept answers, if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

Suppose $f$ has an infinite number of zeros $z$ for which $f'(x)$ is a constant $M_z\not = 0$ in a small neighborhood of $z$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_n$ be zeros of $f$ and $E_i \ni z_i$ be connected components of $\{x : |f(x)| < \varepsilon\}$ such that $f'|_{E_i} = M_i \not = 0$. Denote by $l(E_i)$ the measure of $E_i$. Then $l(E_i) |M_i| = 2\varepsilon$ and
$$
\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{|f| < \varepsilon} |f'(x)| dx \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n l(E_i)|M_i| = 2n.
$$
Taking $\varepsilon > 0$ sufficiently small, we can find an arbitrarily large number $n$ of such zeros $z_i$ and components $E_i$. The supremum is therefore infinite.

**Note:** The argument could be refined and applied to $f(x) = x^3 \sin (1/x)$, defined on $[0,1]$, for instance.